# explain this nested printf statement

Tags: c, printf

```
int a = 5;

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", printf("hi!") * printf("bye"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hi!bye9
```

I would like to know how the order in which the output has occurred. Does this mean `printf` function returns a value?

What is the reason behind inner `printf` statements being executed first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the internal `printf`s is unspecified. Another implementation, the same implementation with different compiler settings, or the same implementation with the same code in a different place might produce `byehi!9`.

The 9 comes because `printf` returns the number of characters printed, so the two internal `printf`s return 3 and the `*` is the familiar multiplication operator, giving 9.

Comment: It is not undefined it is unspecified, big difference

Comment: Technically that's two words... :)

Answer (score 7):

This program exhibits [unspecified behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) since the order of evaluation of sub expressions is unspecified except where it is specifically defined:

```
printf("%d",printf("hi!")*printf("bye"));
            ^             ^
            1             2
```

So either 1 or 2 could be evaluated first and you can not determine which. We can see this from the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5` *Expressions* paragraph *3* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74) Except as specified
>   later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified**.

Yes, [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) does have a return value, which is the number of character printed or `-1` if there is an error, in this case assuming no error the return value will be `3` for both the inner `printf`s

The arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is called which is why the inner `printf`s are executed first, this is covered in section `6.5.2.2` *Function calls* paragraph *4*:

> An argument may be an expression of any object type. **In preparing for the call to a
>   function, the arguments are evaluated**, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
>   corresponding argument.81)

Answer (score 2):

`printf` like other IO functions returns the number of bytes printed.

This is done so that you can check if IO went as expected, since file / stream IO errors can happen and sometimes the only way to know that is to check that the right number of bytes got printed.

Answer (score 2):

printf returns the number of bytes written.  So the "hi!" and "bye" return 3 each.  3*3 is 9 and that's what is printed

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` returns the number of characters (bytes) it printed successfully. Please read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) of `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You get `hi!bye9` because `printf` returns the number of bytes output or a negative number if there is an error.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/:

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>   If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.

So with:

```
printf("%d",printf("hi!")*printf("bye"));
```

First of all the two inner `printf` calls output `hi!` followed by `bye`. Then the return values from those two get interpreted similar to the below (they get multiplied together and output by the outer `printf`):

```
printf("%d", 3 * 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note that**

1. `printf` is function of standard library and most of library functions return something.
2. It returns the length of what you want to write inside the `" "`.
3. If you have a space inside the `printf` function it will be add it in the length.

---

**Example**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
     int x;
     x=printf("xyz \n");
     printf("%d",x);
     getch();
}
```

Here, the first `printf` statement executes then it returns the value of the
first `printf` which is 4. Then we store this value in variable `x` and print the variable. So output will be:

```
xyz
4
```

Here value is 4 because we used a space